# Bootstrap popover does not work with downloaded js and css

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I am having some weird problem with using `popover` in my django app. When using the css and js of a **latest version** of `bootstrap` it simply does not work. When I use link to **3.4.1** version I found in some tutorial everything works just fine. I'm attaching code that doesn't work and the one that does.
Did popover function got removed in latest bootstrap?

### Works (3.5.1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
</script>
```

### Does not work (4.5.x):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried the code with a CDN and it all works fine, so probably there is something wrong with your static_url / static_root. Can you show us how you configured that in your settings.py ?

Comment: Have you looked at the URL that is being rendered in your browser? Do you get a 404 when clicking on the CSS/JS links? You may be referencing the wrong location for the files or your static settings within `settings.py` may be wrong.

Comment: I'm even more confused now. I copied `popover.min.js` into my staticfiles location (simply `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in my `settings.py`) and it loads- `[02/Dec/2020 10:22:58] "GET /static/js/popover.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0` but there is NOTHING about other files, nothing in log.

Comment: It looks like it just does not show it every time. So no errors on static files. Everything works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **popper.js**.
Note that the [bootstrap bundle js](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js) include the `popper.js` library. Try to load this one from CDN instead of `bootstrap.js`.
Require order :

1. Jquery
2. Popper
3. Bootstrap

Comment: That was it! I just included jquery and then the whole bootstrap bundle and it does work. Thanks!